# Great Gatsby - Thesis Statement

Tags: books

This is my thesis regarding the American Dream's unattainability.I need a fourth point at the end. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

In F. Scott Fitzgerald's "The Great Gatsby," the American Dream is illustrated as unattainable by Gatsby's failure to recapture the love of Daisy Buchanan, his false satisfaction from money, inability to achieve higher social status, and ...

Comment: I voted for close. This is a questiopn about literature.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about literature analysis, not the English language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known fact that none of the Gatsby's friends came to his funeral except for Nick. Therefore, I think putting *incompetence to gain true relationship* as a fourth point would be a good idea.

Comment: It's a good point, but how does this relate to the American Dream?

Comment: American Dream is usually recognized by many people as fame and wealth. But since you have mentioned Gatsby's failure to recapture the love of Daisy, I assumed your definition of American Dream might have been related to the relationship as well as fame and wealth.